# Dynamically change height of slide for jssor

Tags: jssor

I'm using [jssor](http://www.jssor.com) plugin for slideshow of my content. There is a bunch of configuration options, which is great, but I can't find one for dynamically changing height of slide, and not sure if that is possible at all.

I see that one must specify height and width of outer container, and that slides will take its width and height. But can that be changed on the fly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope the $ScaleHeight api help.

```
instance.$ScaleHeight(); //Get scaled height
instance.$ScaleHeight(height); //Scale the slider to new height and keep aspect ratio.
```

Comment: Yes, I already switched to another plugin. I was in a bit of rush for this. But this should be helpful for someone else.